# How to choose k grid using pymatgen for VASP?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, k-points, convergence-test, pymatgen

Before I start; sorry for this lengthy question.

I am confused about choosing the correct set of K points for the K-convergence test for VASP calculations. The system of my interest has an **orthorhombic** structure with a=**7** A,b=**11.5** A,c=**6.5** A lattice constants. How can I choose the correct set of K points?

It’s so confusing!!!!!
Please help.

Comment: +1 but one question per post please (that's why I edited this). Also please check previous questions on this site: people have asked how to choose k-points before.

Comment: Does this Q&A help? https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/10584/can-someone-guide-me-on-how-to-get-the-k-point-file-for-a-vasp-simulation/10585#10585. Essentially, it is helpful to think in terms of a single kpoint density parameter that you vary.